# Graphing the tangent to a curve in real time with Manipulate

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, education

The function $4-x^{2}-2y^{2}$

Set $y = 1$

Then <1,1,1>

And its derivative at $y = 1$ is

$$f'(x,1) = -2x$$

The following plot the curve at $y = 1$ intersecting the surface, and the derivative at that point.

My question is, how do I work out the formula to plot a `Manipulate` plot that allows me to move the tangent (derivative) along the curve in real time? I just can't seem to work out the solution.

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot3D[{{t, 1, 2 - t^2}, {1 + t, 1, 1 - 2 t}, {t, -3, 3}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}], 
  {k, -4, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: There are already many questions relating to tangents.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=tangent Have you made an effort to skim these?

Comment: The first few lines are incomplete sentences, and $f'(x,1)$ is improper notation, however you define $f$, I think.